# How can I compare two system restore points?

Tags: windows-xp, comparison, system-restore

I have a problem that did not exist at a previous system restore point. I want to find out the difference. Is there a built-in or third party program that can list the differences?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a tool that can compare restore points.

However, as explained more in detail in [Dump Registry to text files for tracking](http://www.zdnetasia.com/techguide/windows/0,39044904,62049103,00.htm), you can very simply restore the two and then export the entire registry as two (huge) text files. You can then use a text compare utility to find out the differences.

If you choose this solution, don't forget to create a current system restore point that you can return to.

Answer (score 0):

Restore points are very protected by the system so viruses will not be able to miss with them that's why it is somewhat hard to compare restore points.

Ironically, a virus-infected system will include viruses in the restore point :)